# Monitoring PHP file access with loggedfs - access denied

Tags: filesystems, apache-httpd

I am trying to see how many files are included for each page call on my site. When I run:

```
sudo loggedfs -f /path/to/webroot
```

I get a printout of files - I think from a cron job that might be running. But when I try to access the site, Apache gives me an access denied page. As soon as I cancel loggedfs, Apache serves up the page correctly.

I thought loggedfs was supposed to be passive and not affect access to files - is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Loggedfs is based on [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). By default, FUSE filesystems are available only to the user who mounted them. (Whether exposing files to other users is dangerous depends on what the filesystem is doing about permissions.) With [loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/loggedfs.html), to expose files to all users, you need to pass the `-p` option.

```
sudo loggedfs -p -f /path/to/webroot
```

If you use ACL, you may run into a second hurdle: many FUSE filesystems don't support ACLs, and loggedfs in particular doesn't. I don't have a good solution for this.

I'm not convinced that loggedfs is the right tool for this particular job: you won't be able to trace which page triggered the loading of which file. I'm not familiar with Apache, but surely it must have tracing tools for this task.